# Angular Project not being tracked by git

Tags: angular, git, bitbucket

I created an Angular 5 project in a local branch, but when I add/commit/push that branch to origin, the angular project doesn't show up in my branch in the remote repository (on bitbucket).

Bitbucket even tells me that the commit was made, but it just doesn't show the angular 5 project.

The funny thing is, it worked for master, but when it doesn't on any other local branch.

I don't know what's going on / how to fix this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When you say it worked for `master`, did you commit your new project in `master` and then checkout another - existing - branch and try to commit the project again?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what I mean

Comment: You have committed your project in `master`, you can merge `master` in to your other branch.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to set the upstream for pushing. Could you try the below?

From the branch you want to push:

```
git config push.default current
git push
```

This should create on bitbucket a branch with the same name as the branch you currently are pushing.